# Java Regex to validate group field pattern example - abc.def.gh1

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am just writing some piece of java code where I need to validate groupId (maven) passed by user.
`For example - com.fb.test1`.

I have written regex which says string should not start and end with '.' and can have alphanumeric characters delimited by '.'

```
[^\.][[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.{0,1}]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

But this regex not able to find out consecutive '.' `For example - com..fb.test`. I have added {0,1} followed by decimal to restrict it limitation to 1 but it didnt work.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: basically `[a-zA-Z0-9]++(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]++)*` ?

Answer (score 0):

The quantifier `{0,1}` and the dot should not be in the character class, because you are repeating the whole character class allowing for 0 or more dots, including `{` `,` `}` chars.

You can also exclude a dot to the left using a negative lookbehind instead of matching an actual character that is not a dot.

In Java you could write the pattern as

```
(?<!\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Note that the `$` makes sure that that match is at the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxh5Zh/1)